# Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource matching "autoloader" not found

Tags: zend-framework, zend-autoloader, zend-app-bootstrap

I am new to Zend framework. I am updating a project which was developed by another person. I am getting an error like,

```
Generating config... PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception  
'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource matching "autoloader" not found' 
in /project/aggrep/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:692

Stack trace:

#0 /project/aggrep/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(627):      
Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('autoloader')

#1 /project/aggrep/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(584):  
Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap('autoloader')

#2 /project/aggrep/library/Zend/Application.php(355): 
Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap('autoloader')

#3 /project/aggrep/process/init.php(27): Zend_Application->bootstrap('autoloader')

#4 /project/scripts/generate_distro.php(3): require('/project/aggrep...')

#5 {main}

thrown in /project/aggrep/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php on line 692
Done
```

What I need to do or what I need to check? Anyone please help me?

Thanks,
Looking forward!

Comment: Start at line 27 in /project/aggrep/process/init.php; you can probably comment it out, but it may effect the application.  For some reason a file or function call cannot be found now.

Comment: can you post your code from Bootstrap.php

Comment: Are there any lines in your `application.ini` file that look like `resources.autoloader.XXX`?

Answer (score 2):

This kind of error comes from an improper bootstrapping.

In your `Bootstrap.php` there are a bunch of functions starting with `_init`, eg. `public function _initAutoload()`. All of these are automatically executed upon application launch, but if a particular order is needed, one can use `$this->bootstrap('autoload');` in one of these functions, to make sure, that the resource `_initAutoload()` has been executed.

It is more than likely, that a function in `Bootstrap.php` is requesting a resource `_initAutoload()` which doesn't exist/has been renamed.